# call a method once every time certain pages load (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom form directive that is likely to be used multiple times per page. I need a total count of these directives, and so added one outside the directive config object, i.e.,

```
module.directive("customInput", [
    function ()
    {
        /*
         * Because each instance of the directive will get its own
         * instance of the return object, we have to declare groupCount
         * here, instead of inside the post-link function where it's used.
         */
        var groupCount = {};

        return { ...configObj... }
    }
]);
```

The problem is that this count persists across views. I moved it to a service and gave it a reset method, but I need a way to call that method only once per page.

I don't want to add a `$routeChangeSuccess` listener, because that seems too heavy an approach for just the few pages that use these inputs. I can't do it in the directive's controller (e.g. `$watch("$viewContentLoaded")`), because that executes multiple times.

I don't want to put the burden on individual view controllers if there's a way to do it once. Is there (maybe with a "parent" directive)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the counter in a service so that it has some nice increment and decrement methods. Based on [Matthew Berg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/973651/mathew-berg)'s suggestion of using `$destroy`, I can call the service's decrement method. My estimate is that this solution is a little heavier than a one-off reset call, but not as bad as a watch on route changes.

```
// recommended var name for this object: groupControl
module.service("GroupControlSvc", [
    function ()
    {
        this.groupCount = {};

        this.incrementGroupCount = function (groupName)
        {
            if (!this.groupCount.hasOwnProperty(groupName)) {
                this.groupCount[groupName] = 0;
            }
            this.groupCount[groupName]++;
        };

        this.decrementGroupCount = function (groupName)
        {
            if (this.groupCount.hasOwnProperty(groupName)) {
                console.log("decrementing group " + groupName);
                this.groupCount[groupName]--;

                if (this.groupCount[groupName] === 0) {
                    console.log("removing group " + groupName);
                    delete this.groupCount[groupName];
                }
            }
        };
    }
]);


module.directive("customInput", [
    function ()
    {
        return {
            ...
            ,link: function (scope, elem, attrs)
            {
                ...

                /*
                 * Count the members of each group, so we can
                 * determine which element is last. Because
                 * groupCount is an object (and an object of
                 * objects, at that), assigning it to scope
                 * here is by reference. Thus, every scope
                 * instance will point to the same object.
                 */
                if (attrs.hasOwnProperty("editGroup")) {
                    groupControl.incrementGroupCount(attrs.editGroup);
                }
                scope.groupCount = groupControl.groupCount;

                scope.$on("$destroy", function ()
                {
                    groupControl.decrementGroupCount(attrs.editGroup);
                });
            } // end post-link function
        };
    }
]);
```

I'd like to not expose the `groupCount` property directly, but assigning a getter function to scope instead isn't worth it right now.

This also leaves me open to the possibility that `groupCount` is skewed by a failure in `$destroy` or its callback.

***While this solves my need, it does not answer the question asked.***

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved at the architectural level, and AngularJS has a great mechanism for this kind of thing. Take a page out of how mobile apps are commonly written, and make a "manager" service. A service in Angular is a singleton, so it can maintain variables like collections of objects (directives) and counts of those items. It can then be asked for those things whenever they're needed, it can be asked to create/alter/delete them. It can also be the source of the data when you're doing something like an ngRepeat, instead of storing the data right in your controller.

Communications-driven models do this a lot, and it works very well. Suppose you have a hypothetical "buddy list". You could do something like this:

```
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MainDisplay', function($scope, buddyManager) {
    $scope.buddyManager = buddyManager;

    // Handle things here that are relevant to the main display
    $scope.sendMessage = function(buddy) {
      alert('here I could message ' + buddy.name);
    }

    buddyManager.addBuddy('Susan');
    buddyManager.addBuddy('David');
    buddyManager.addBuddy('Jamie');
  })
  .service('buddyList', function() {
    var self = this;

    this.buddies = [];
    this.buddyCount = 0; // If you didn't want to just do buddies.length...

    this.addBuddy = function(name) {
      // Again, if you didn't want to just use .length...
      self.buddyCount++;
      self.buddies.push({
        name: name
      });
    };
  })
  .directive('buddy', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: { buddy: '=' },
      template: '<div class="buddy">{{ name }}</div>',
      link: function($scope) {
        // Here you can put anything specific to a buddy, like click handlers
        // $scope.buddy is yourself / your buddy data
      }
    };
  });
```

And a simple page:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<!-- You know you what you need... -->
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainDisplay">
  <buddy ng-repeat="buddy in buddyManager.buddies" buddy="buddy"></buddy>
</body>
</html>
```

Working Plnkr here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/R3QMwLxEbqMRlBg74dOi?p=preview

Comment: I am aware of the role of services. When I go to another route/view, the `buddyList` service--and the count, in particular--persists. Can you clarify how this answers my question?

Comment: You asked for a way to call the method only once per page... Putting it into a service would allow you to do that because the service is a singleton. For example, suppose you were using ui-router. This emits a $stateChangeStart event on every page transition. You could simply listen for this in your service and perform the operation you want done one time when this happens. Every router has something like this, so you should be able to hook any of them no matter which it is.

Comment: From OP: "I don't want to add a `$routeChangeSuccess` listener". There is nothing about a service, AFAIK, that allows it to invoke a method once per view/route.

Comment: That statement was made on the basis of this option seeming "heavy", but that doesn't make it the wrong thing to do. Listening to events in AngularJS is actually MUCH more efficient than using watchers because it only has to iterate a shallow array of cheap callbacks, and only as needed. You said you wanted to execute something once per page load, and this event does precisely that. Doing it in a service guarantees you'll only respond once.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen in on scopes to just increment if you want. Something like:

```
module.directive("customInput", [
    function (){
        /*
         * Because each instance of the directive will get its own
         * instance of the return object, we have to declare groupCount
         * here, instead of inside the post-link function where it's used.
         */
        var groupCount = {};

        var totalCount = 0;

        return {
            link: function(scope){
                totalCount++;
                scope.$on("$destroy", function(){
                    totalCount--
                });
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

totalCount will always be the number of elements you have. You can wire into whatever you want (service etc...) if you want to use it.

Comment: Decrementing on `$destroy` is a good idea. I expanded upon this in my own answer.